# Android Most Efficient way for encrypting/decrypting continuous UDP (voice packets) data

Tags: android, encryption, udp, voip

I am using Speex library to encode/decode bytearray in a p2p voice chat application. 
 I have tried using AES encryption but due to the encryption and decryption , my UI thread hangs up. I will try to write the problem in pseudo code.

OnPlayer Side:

```
while(keep_on_running) {
socket.receive(packet); 
encodedFrame = AESEncrytion.decrypt(encodedFrame);
Speex.decode(encodedFrame, encodedFrame.length, pcmFrame);
```

}

On Recorder Side:

```
while(keep_on_running) {
Speex.encode(pcmFrame, encodedFrame);       
AESEncrytion.encrypt(encodedFrame);
socket.send(packet)
```

}

I would like to the know the best possible ways to encrpyt/decrypt continuous steream of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to encrypt/decrypt a continuous stream of data is (wait for it) using a stream cipher or a block cipher in stream cipher mode.

The issue with block cipher modes of operation (such as CBC or - the insecure - ECB mode) is that they require full blocks of data for each encrypt/decryption operation. This means you have to supply 16 bytes at a time for AES. This can easily lead to the blocking issues you are experiencing.

Now if you would use [AES counter mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) encryption then you have several advantages:

- you can pre-compute the "key stream" which should help to combat issues with latency (AKA lagging)
- you can simply decrypt each byte as it comes in
- it's relatively easy to convert a stream into [GCM mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) authenticated encryption (authenticated encryption is as good as a must for confidential communication)
- you may be able to use multi-threaded CTR implementations to speed up encryption/decryption

If you run into performance issues you may also take a look at specialized stream ciphers such as the popular [Salsa20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) stream cipher. Stream ciphers are often generated specifically for high efficiency / high bandwidth communication.

[EDIT]

Note that [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) has also been defined to work on UDP packages. If you are not sure about implementing your own transport protocol, it would be much better to use a standardized option. Note that you may not find a library that supports this out of the box for your runtime.

Quote from Wikipedia:

> However, it has also been implemented with datagram-oriented transport
>   protocols, such as the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) and the Datagram
>   Congestion Control Protocol (DCCP), usage which has been standardized
>   independently using the term Datagram Transport Layer Security ([DTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security)).

Comment: But would it be usefull in encrypting/decrypting data from UDP packets. Some of the packets are lost too...

Comment: @SoH for sure - as long as you have a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) (called the IV in many crypto libraries) that you can keep synchronized at both sides